# How to set up git repo on my subdomain?

Tags: ssh, centos, git, repository, subdomain

I have a centOS VPS and I have install git.

However, I want to set up a git repo on a subdomain on one of the domains hosted on my vps in order so I can push there for testing.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Two options are to use the simple ssh setup from the git book [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) or [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite). I prefer [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) though since you would then have fine grained control over permissions. There are other protocols that you could use as well, but ssh has been in my experience the easiest to set up.

Once you have your subdomain pointing at your VPS ip you can clone and push to it directly via the git ssh protocol. For example:

```
git clone git@git.website.com:my_repo
```

This example assumes the following:

- Your ssh username is **git**
- Your sub domain is **git.website.com**
- Your repositories name is **my_repo**